# Delete messages and reset topic offset to 0 irrespective of consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, ksqldb, kafka-topic

I need to create a Kafka setup where at the start of each day, all messages in a topic must get deleted and its offset reset to 0.

I have tried to do this by setting log.retention to 1 day but it didn't seem to work. I also ran `kafka-delete-records`. It did delete all the messages but `kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell` still gave me the latest offset. I want it to go to 0.

Also, I am not explicitly setting a consumer group. They are internal ones like `_confluent-ksql-default_transient_929377247691956102_1560973030312`. So I want the offset for the topic to be reset to 0 irrespective of the consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reset the head offset of a topic in Kafka, except to delete the topic and create a new one with the same name.

You can also use the admin api to delete consumer groups.